# Find matching sets in a database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a junction table in a (SQL Server 2014) database with columns FirstID and SecondID. Given a specific FirstID, I'd like to find all other FirstIDs from the table that have an equivalent set of SecondIDs (even if that set is empty).
Sample Data:

```
FirstId      SecondId
1            1
1            2
2            3
3            1
3            2
...          ...
```

In the case of the sample data, if I specified FirstID = 1, then I'd expect 3 to appear in the result set.

I've tried the following so far, which works pretty well except for empty sets:

```
SELECT FirstSecondEqualSet.FirstId
FROM FirstSecond FirstSecondOriginal
INNER JOIN FirstSecond FirstSecondEqualSet ON FirstSecondOriginal.SecondId = FirstSecondEqualSet.SecondId
WHERE FirstSecondOriginal.FirstId = @FirstId 
    AND FirstSecondEqualSet.FirstId != @FirstId
GROUP BY FirstSecondEqualSet.FirstId
HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FirstSecond WHERE FirstSecond.FirstId = @FirstId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's somehow related to *Relational Division with no Remainder (RDNR)*. See this great [**article**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/) by Dwain Camps for reference.

```
DECLARE @firstId INT = 1

SELECT
    f2.FirstId
FROM FirstSecond f1
INNER JOIN FirstSecond f2 
    ON f2.SecondId = f1.SecondId
    AND f1.FirstId <> f2.FirstId
WHERE
    f1.FirstId = @firstId
GROUP BY f2.FirstId
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FirstSecond WHERE FirstId = @firstId)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is basically the same thing I wrote in my question (the only difference being that you moved f1.FirstId <> f2.FirstId from the WHERE clause to the JOIN expression, which is interpreted identically by most RDBMS engines).

Comment: Oh right, I'm sorry. Can you elaborate on the *empty set* problem?

Comment: Edited: Nevermind, I just realized the empty set thing makes no sense without domain context, and SO is not really the right venue for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.  It counts the number of values for each `firstid` and then joins on the `secondid`.

```
select fs2.firstid
from (select fs1.*, count(*) over (partition by firstid) as numseconds
      from firstsecond fs1
      where fs1.firstid = @firstid
     ) fs1 join
     (select fs2.*, count(*) over (partition by firstid) as numseconds
      from firstsecond fs2
     ) fs2
     on fs1.secondid = fs2.secondid and fs1.numseconds = fs2.numseconds
group by fs2.firstid
having count(*) = max(fs1.numseconds);
```